# Singleton in Asp.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In my app, I create a dbcontext for every call and dependency inject it through Ninject.

I've been thinking of creating a singleton class (ContextManager - BaseController would set the context on every request) to make the context available from everywhere, thus allowing all the services to share the same context. This would furthermore make it easy to, for example, disable proxy creating etc. seeing as the context is managed from one place only.

However, seeing as the object is a singleton object the context would be overwritten per each request which won't work for me (I don't want multiple requests sharing a single context).

What would be the best way to do this (how to preferably a single context ONLY in request scope)?

Comment: is this asp.net MVC?

Comment: @Paddy
Well yea but I'm using Web API 2.

Comment: How is creating a singleton different/better than using Ninject? Ninject can maintain a singleton instance of your context and pass it around or create a new one per request etc.

Comment: Also since we're on the topic, Ninject is the slowest of all DI containers. I've since then stopped using Ninject and use SimpleInjector which is one of the fatest.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan: How much did that improve your average response time?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Not sure. I still use it in the apps that were built with it, however any new projects use SimpleInjector. Why? Similar setup time so why not use the one that claims to be significantly quicker? I'm betting a mom and pop app won't notice a difference, but in an enterprise scenario you might see the benefits. Are you using Ninject in your apps?

Comment: @TheMuffinMan: Yeah, we were using it before SimpleInjector existed. I'm trying to figure out if the performance difference is enough to merit the effort of converting our binding code. I've heard about the benchmarks, but nobody's been able to provide real-world metrics yet. The framework may be 100 times slower, but if that translates to 1ms per request I really don't care.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Also you might have other things that could be performance tweaked which could make more of a difference... caching, leveraging async methods etc.. What I've done in the past is slowly work in a replacement. For example we changed from EF to PetaPoco and I did it for new stuff and slowly went back. (I wanted the flexibility of raw sql statements with the convenience of a mapper).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're describing is not a Singleton, but a Request-Scoped object. ASP.NET MVC has strong support for dependency injection, and you should allow your DI bindings to determine where the context comes from, rather than instantiating it yourself. Ninject has binding syntax to support this. I think it goes:

```
Bind<DataContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

As long as you are using good Dependency-Injection patterns consistently, this should cause the same `DataContext` instance to be passed to every dependency you have within the same request.

The advantage to relying on Dependency Injection for construction of your context is that if you want to change details like disabling change tracking on the context, you can simply change your DI binding to use a custom method or factory, and the rest of your code doesn't have to change at all.

Answer (score 3):

Singleton is not the right approach here, but this is not too hard to implement, by simply instantiating  your data context in your controller and injecting it into your service classes, e.g.:

```
public class SomeController {

     private DataContext _context;
     private SomeService _service;

     public SomeController() {
          _context = ...InstantiateContext();
          _service = new SomeService(_context);
     }   
}
```

This also allows makes it relatively simple to inject your context into your controller if you wish to unit test that.  You can also relatively simply dispose of your context by coding this into the dispose method of the controller class (as noted above, a base controller class may be useful).

A singleton carries some persistent state  - this is anathema to unit testing and will ultimately give you difficulties in your code.